# Learning assembly: Sum less significant bytes

Tags: assembly, x86

So I'm trying to sum the two less significant bytes of an 32 bits variable (declared in the .s file but attributed in the .c file). My initial idea was to move this variable to %eax and to %ebx and then do addw %ax, %bx.

Here's what i have:

```
.section .data

numero:
    .int 5

.section .text
.global soma_byte #int soma_byte(void)

soma_byte:

movl numero, %eax       
movl numero, %ebx
addw %ax, %bx       
ret
```

I want to return to .c the result of the sum... Is that possible? Am i doing something stupid here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `sum the two less significative bytes of an 32 bits variable` means what you were trying to do. You were just adding the two bytes to themselves. In your example, the two bytes were `0` and `5` (input is `00000005h`) so your result is `10` not `5` that I would expect.

To add the two least significant bytes together, you could do:

```
movzbl numero, %eax    # fetch least significant byte
movzbl numero+1, %edx  # fetch second byte
add %edx, %eax         # add them
ret
```

If however you really want to add the low word to itself, you can do:

```
movzwl numero, %eax    # fetch the low word (2 bytes)
add %eax, %eax         # add to itself
ret
```

PS: the calling convention mandates `ebx` to be preserved.

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly the same as what you were asking, but the low/high byte registers can be useful for getting at bytes of a larger value without shifts or storing/reloading.

```
movzwl numero, %eax    # load the low 16b
add %ah, %al           # add the high 8 to the low 8
```

This is only an 8bit add, so it can overflow.  If that's a problem, use Jester's way of unpacking the bytes to different registers before adding.

Result in `al`, the low 8b of eax.  `ah`, the high 8b of `ax`, still holds the 2nd byte of the original number.

If this is going to be a whole function that returns in eax, instead of just a sequence as part of a larger function, then you'd need something like `movzbl %al, %eax` to zero extend.  `cbw` will sign-extend al to ax.  `cbw` is a single-byte opcode (smaller code size than `movzx`), but only writes the low16 of eax, so reading eax will cause a partial-register slowdown on some CPUs.

Comment: Except the prototype says `int` so you need to use that `movzbl` you mention, so where is the saved instruction? :P Also your code doesn't handle carry/overflow properly it truncates the sum to 8 bits.

Comment: @Jester: Thanks for pointing that out; I didn't read the question carefully since it was already answered.  I was going to leave a comment on your answer, then decided it would be easier to read as an answer.  I thought the `*h` registers were a useful thing to point out for this sort of thing, so I fixed my answer to maybe be more helpful and not misleading.